# array[i].readBook is undefined (Library The Odin Project)

Tags: javascript

Whenever I create 2 books with the 'Read:' as false and make the first book true by pressing the 'Read' button then delete that first one, it keeps saying "library.html:83 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'readBook')". I'm not really sure what's wrong as I have tried console logging the boolean values for array[i].readBook.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Library</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="create-container">
        <button class="create-book">New Book</button>
        <input type="text" id="title" placeholder="Title">
        <input type="text" id="author" placeholder="Author">
        <input type="text" id="pages" placeholder="Pages(Number)">
        <input type="checkbox" id="readAlready">
    </div>
    <div class="books-grid"></div>
    <script>
        let myLibrary = []
        const bookShelf = document.querySelector('.books-grid');
        const createBook = document.querySelector('.create-book');
        const titleInput = document.querySelector('#title');
        const authorInput = document.querySelector('#author');
        const pagesInput = document.querySelector('#pages');
        const readAlreadyInput = document.querySelector('#readAlready');
        const booksGrid = document.querySelector('.books-grid');
        let attributeCount = -1;

        function Book(title, author, pages, readBook) {
            this.title = title;
            this.author = author;
            this.pages = pages;
            this.readBook = readBook;
        }

        function addBookToLibrary() {
            const titleValue = titleInput.value;
            const authorValue = authorInput.value;
            const pagesValue = pagesInput.value;
            const checkBoxChecked = readAlreadyInput.checked;
            const newBook = new Book(titleValue, authorValue, pagesValue, checkBoxChecked);
            myLibrary.push(newBook);
            libraryBooks(myLibrary);
        }

        function libraryBooks(array) {
            for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
                const cardContainer = document.createElement('div');
                const titleDiv = document.createElement('div');
                const authorDiv = document.createElement('div');
                const pagesDiv = document.createElement('div');
                const checkedDiv = document.createElement('div');
                const deleteButton = document.createElement('button');
                const changeReadButton = document.createElement('button');
                cardContainer.style.marginBottom = '20px'
                titleDiv.innerHTML = 'Title: ' + array[i].title;
                authorDiv.innerHTML = 'Author: ' + array[i].author;
                pagesDiv.innerHTML = 'Pages: ' + array[i].pages;
                checkedDiv.innerHTML = 'Read: ' + array[i].readBook;
                deleteButton.innerHTML = 'Delete';
                console.log(array[i].readBook)
                if (array[i].readBook == true) {
                    changeReadButton.innerHTML = 'Not Read';
                } else if (array[i].readBook == false) {
                    changeReadButton.innerHTML = 'Read';
                } 
                cardContainer.appendChild(titleDiv);  
                cardContainer.appendChild(authorDiv);
                cardContainer.appendChild(pagesDiv);
                cardContainer.appendChild(checkedDiv);
                cardContainer.appendChild(deleteButton);
                cardContainer.appendChild(changeReadButton);
                bookShelf.appendChild(cardContainer);
                deleteButton.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
                    i = 0
                    console.log(i)
                    cardContainer.parentNode.removeChild(cardContainer)
                    array.splice(i, 1)
                    console.log(myLibrary);
                })
                changeReadButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
                    if (array[i].readBook == true) {
                        checkedDiv.innerHTML = 'Read: ' + 'false';
                        array[i].readBook = false;
                        changeReadButton.innerHTML = 'Read';
                    } else if (array[i].readBook == false) {
                        checkedDiv.innerHTML = 'Read: ' + 'true';
                        array[i].readBook = true;
                        changeReadButton.innerHTML = 'Not Read';
                    }
                })
            }
        } 

        createBook.addEventListener('click', function() {
            booksGrid.innerHTML = '';
            addBookToLibrary();
        })
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `array.splice(i, 1)` changes the length of array ... so, if you remove the first one, the second one was `array[1]` but is now `array[0]` and since `i` hasn't changed for the eventListener callback, `array[i]` is `undefined` and won't have `readBook` property of course - in other words `i` does not change inside the callback, so it will refer to the wrong element in array if you've changed array

Comment: @JaromandaX I added i = 0 in the changeReadButton event listener (as shown below) in hopes of resetting the index of i to the start of the array and it worked, but now I have a new problem. It seems like each read button is following the same boolean value. For example, when I create 2 books with read set to false and press read on either one of the books, then try to change the reading status of the other book, it doesn't change after the first click, but does change after the 2nd click. Each book status button change click alternates from false --> true --> false.Any idea on how to fix this?

Comment: adding `i=0` will fix the problem for 2 initial items in the array ... not 3 or more ... so, that isn't any sort of solution - sorry, but I can't tell what you want your code to do, not from your description or from reading the code - it's beyond my abilities, so, sorry I can't provide any more insight than I have

Comment: oh... thanks for trying to help anyways